# Python: доступ к вложенному объекту json

Tags: python, json

Через json.load в обработку берется json следующего содержания:

```
{
  "tickets": [
    {
       "custom_fields": [
        {
          "id": "some_id",
          "value": "some_data"
        },
        {
          "id": "THIS_ID",
          "value": "SOUGHT_DATA1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
       "custom_fields": [
        {
          "id": "some_id",
          "value": "some_data"
        },
        {
          "id": "THIS_ID",
          "value": "SOUGHT_DATA2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "count": 2
}
```

Я прекрасно понимаю, как мне получить tickets или count через json.get. А как мне получить значения из value, у которых id == 'THIS_ID'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переберите их обычным циклом, например:

```
for ticket in source['tickets']:
    for fields in ticket['custom_fields']:
        if fields['id'] == 'THIS_ID':
            print(fields['value'])
```